# What should I do as Subversion refuses to commit after I moved some files

Tags: svn

I'm single user of svn on my pc. I just moved some files and changed some lines. Then subversion refuses to commit saying files were lacking and I have to update.

Can't I move files ?

And I make an update, I will lose my work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with Subversion, you can't just move files because the Subversion repository won't know what happened. As far as the repository is concerned, the files have just disappeared. If you want to move files, you have to do it through Subversion; the exact procedure varies depending on how you access Subversion (command line, TortoiseSVN, etc.).

I don't think updating would trash your data, but I wouldn't advise it yet. Subversion will update your working copy with the latest revision from the repository; I'm not quite sure what Subversion would do with two new unversioned files lying around. My hunch is that it wouldn't touch them, but I'm not sure.

The best thing for you to do is probably move the files back to their original location and then move them again, this time using Subversion. This way, you retain the file histories.

Comment: This is correct -- move the files back to their original locations and use `svn move` to move them to the desired new locations.

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't know one couldn't move the files.